# Working with latitude/longitude values in Java/MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I have a database table containing location latitude and longitude. I am given following values latitude, longitude, minX, minY, maxX, maxY. I need to return all the records from database table whose lat, long fall within the range.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a [PreparedStatement](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html&ei=TPiRUe_PE-j3igK_xoDgBg&usg=AFQjCNEwPC9v1eeY-SUnjnzVBU-MziNU9A&sig2=HsYjozQfEUFP9YdmHLucig&bvm=bv.46471029,d.cGE) anytime you need to make a complex SQL query such as this. Here's some pseduocode to give you an idea of what you'll be doing:

```
String query = "SELECT * from `DBTableName` WHERE latitude >= ? AND latitude <= ? AND     
longitude >= ? AND longitude <= ?`";

PreparedStatement ps = connection.PrepareStatement(query);
ps.setLong(1, minX);
ps.setLong(2, maxX);
ps.setLong(3, minY);
ps.setLong(4, maxY); 
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

The list of records satisfying your query will then be accessible via the `ResultSet`

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got the question.

Try

```
SELECT * FROM locationTable
WHERE (latitude >= minX AND latitude =< maxX)
AND ( longitude >= minY AND longitude =< maxY)
```